# How to calculate angle between 3 polar coordinate points?

Tags: python, polar-coordinates

```
FY00 = [0, 0]

FY01 = [100, 0]

FY02 = [98, 40.10]
```

I have 3 points like this, first param is ρ, second param is θ, I want calculate ∠FY00-FY01-FY02 using python, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a problem with the math or with the implementation?

For the former, for any point (ρ, θ), you can translate to Cartesian coordinates via

```
x = ρ cosθ
y = ρ sinθ
```

Once you get the Cartesian coordinates of all three points, you get the vectors

```
v = B - A
u = C - A
```

where `A` are the coordinates of the vertex of the angle. Finally, after you have the vectors `v` and `u`, you simply write

```
∠BAC = arccos[(u.v)/|u||v|]
```

For the latter, well, post your attempts and ask why they're not working.

Comment: Thanks I know this math process, I just want to find a more simple way to approach it.

Comment: What is not simple about this approach?